How to diagnose and correct timeouts in functions that use connection pooling in the backend?
I'm facing timeout issues in several functions of my backend application, such as confirm-email, start-exam and get-genders. After reviewing the logs, we suspect the issue may be related to the database connection pool configuration.
Oracle
ORM/Driver: TypeORM
poolMin: 2
poolMax: 5
import 'dotenv/config'
import 'reflect-metadata'

import OracleDB from 'oracledb'
import path from 'path'
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'

if (['development', 'test'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV!)) {
  OracleDB.initOracleClient({ libDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './oracledb') })
}

const createDataSource = () => {
  return new DataSource({
    type: 'oracle',
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    connectString: process.env.DB_CONNECT_STRING,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: ['development', 'test'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV!),
    entities: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../models/**/*{.ts,.js}')],
    migrations: [],
    subscribers: [],
    extra: {
      poolMin: Number(process.env.DB_POOL_MIN),
      poolMax: Number(process.env.DB_POOL_MAX)
    }
  })
}

export let DB = createDataSource()

export class DatabaseService {
  private static instance: DatabaseService
  private reconnectTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null
  private healthCheckInterval: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null
  private currentReconnectInterval = 1000 // Start with 1 second
  private readonly MAX_RECONNECT_INTERVAL = 10000 // 10 seconds
  private readonly HEALTH_CHECK_INTERVAL = 10000 // 10 seconds

  public static getInstance(): DatabaseService {
    if (!DatabaseService.instance) {
      DatabaseService.instance = new DatabaseService()
    }
    return DatabaseService.instance
  }

  public async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await DB.initialize()
      console.log('Database connection established')

      this.startHealthCheck()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to database:', error)
      this.handleConnectionError()
    }
  }

  private startHealthCheck(): void {
    if (this.healthCheckInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.healthCheckInterval)
    }

    this.healthCheckInterval = setInterval(async () => {
      try {
        await DB.query('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL')
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Health check failed:', error)
        this.handleConnectionError()
      }
    }, this.HEALTH_CHECK_INTERVAL)
  }

  private handleConnectionError(): void {
    console.log('Database connection lost. Attempting to reconnect...')

    if (this.reconnectTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.reconnectTimeout)
    }

    if (this.healthCheckInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.healthCheckInterval)
    }

    this.reconnectTimeout = setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        if (DB.isInitialized) {
          DB = createDataSource()
        }

        await DB.initialize()
        console.log('Database connection established')

        this.startHealthCheck()
        this.currentReconnectInterval = 1000
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Reconnection attempt failed:', error)
        this.currentReconnectInterval = Math.min(this.currentReconnectInterval * 2, this.MAX_RECONNECT_INTERVAL)
        this.handleConnectionError()
      }
    }, this.currentReconnectInterval)
  }
}

How to fix the timeOuts in my application?

You are getting the following error NJS-040: connection request timeout ?. This error will come when the concurrent incoming requests are large to be served from the pool. In this case you can try increasing poolMax value . some details on these and monitoring stats is here

The infrastructure team increased the poolMax to 10, then to 40. Even so, there were several timeOuts, to be more precise 110.

Is it possible to have test case which simulates the behaviour with tools like ab. Few things that can be checked.    - update node-oracledb version to latest one, 6.7.0.   -  Enable TCP Keepalives expireTime.   -  connectiontimeouts  here

If you are using node-oracledb 6+ in 'Thick' mode via the call to initOracleClient(), or are using an older version of node-oracledb then make sure to increase UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE as shown in the doc - and make sure to set the environment variable BEFORE starting the Node.js process. Also note the doc comments about using a fixed pool size.  Although the dynamic pool size may not be the cause of your current problem, it may prevent you hitting future use issues.
